# Global JS variable to pass HTML chunk to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of HTML I need to send to a React component on page load without rendering it. I'd rather not us AJAX due to cache, but I may revert to that if I can't figure this out.

On the jsp side, I have this:

```
<script>window.banner_data_for_desktop = "...droplet..."</script>
```

This contains the HTML chunk I need to pass

```
<div id="desktop-top-banner">
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

On the jsx side, I've tried rendering directly like this:

```
<div id="top_bar">{window.banner_data_for_desktop}</div>
```

This renders the content, but displays the div tags as a string and not output as HTML.

So then I tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this:

```
<div id="top_bar">dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: window.banner_data_for_desktop }}</div>
```

This results in an error:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__html}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I've tried using Stringify, toString, creating a function to return the html like this:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: window.banner_data_for_desktop};
}
```

All without any luck. If any one has a suggestion to render HTML from the global JS object, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dangerouslySetInnerHtml should be an attribute of the tag:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "HTML CHUNK"}}></div>
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much Felix!!